# Custom set data structure in Ruby

Tags: ruby, set

I wrote a set data structure with some useful functions. I'm not sure if it is a good implementation and if there are other essential functions that a set should support.

```
class CustomSet

  def initialize(list=[])
    @cs =[]
    list.each do |n|
      put(n)
    end
  end

  def size
    @cs.size
  end  

  def each(&blk)
    @cs.each do |n|
      blk.call(n)
    end
  end  

  def index(n)
    @cs.index { |x| x.eql?(n) }
  end 

  def ==(other_object)
    return false unless other_object.class == self.class
    return false unless other_object.size ==self.size
    other_object.each do |n|
      return false unless index(n)  
    end   
    true
  end

  def eql?(other)
    self == other
  end

  def hash
    @cs.reduce(:+){ |n| n.hash }
  end

  def delete(n)
    @cs.delete(n) if index(n)
    self
  end   

  def difference(other)
    CustomSet.new(@cs.select { |n| other.index(n).nil? })
  end  

  def disjoint?(other)
    union(other).size == self.size + other.size 
  end

  def intersection(other)
    CustomSet.new(@cs.select { |n| other.index(n) })
  end 

  def subset?(other)
    self.size >= other.size && intersection(other) == other
  end 

  def union(other)
    u = CustomSet.new(@cs)
    other.each { |n| u.put(n) }
    u 
  end    

  def member?(n)
    index(n)
  end 

  def put(n)
    @cs << n unless index(n)
    self
  end   

  def empty
    @cs = []
    self
  end  

  def to_list
    @cs
  end  

end
```

`Set` treats integers and decimals as distinct elements:

```
irb(main):019:0> Set.new([1,2,3]) == Set.new([1,2.0,3])
=> false
irb(main):020:0> Set.new([1,2,3]) == Set.new([1,2,3])
=> true
irb(main):021:0> 2 == 2.0
=> true
irb(main):022:0> [2] == [2.0]
=> true
irb(main):023:0> Set.new([1,2,3]) == Set.new([1,3,2])
=> true
```

`Set` accepts a range, so the initialize has to copy elements manually unless there is another way.

```
irb(main):029:0> Set.new(1..3) == Set.new([1,3,2])
=> true
```

Comment: Does this do anything that the standard Ruby [`Set` class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) doesn't do?

Comment: Oh, I thought it wasn't available, but besides that I am looking for feedback on general implementation of Set. Also wondering if I did the ==, eql? and hash implementation correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Ruby already has a very nice `Set` class in its standard library. But, as also mentioned, there's still code to review here.

So, review-wise, a few things that caught my eye:

- `@cs`. Sorry, but I'm a stickler for descriptive names. I'm guessing this is supposed to be short for "CustomSet", but that's the name of the class, and the variable is just an array. Something like `@members` might make more sense.
  I'd also add a private accessor method for the variable. Call it `members`, and replace (almost) all instances of `@cs` with `members`. By accessing it though a method, you decouple your code better.
- You constructor is unnecessarily complex. Just `dup`licate the input array:

  ```
    def initialize(list = [])
      @cs = list.dup
    end
  ```
- `#to_list`. "List" isn't a thing in Ruby. Array is a thing though, and the conventional name for this sort of method is `to_a`. However, you don't want to return your instance variable directly! If you do, it can then be modified externally. It also allows external code to keep references, and all manner of other stuff. So return a dup instead.
- `#empty` is self-modifying. It should either be `empty!` to indicate its effect, or it should be called `clear` (to match the so-named method on `Array`). The method should probably also just call `clear` on the internal `@cs` array instead of replacing it.
- `#member?` should perhaps be aliased (or renamed) as `#include?` (again to match `Array`)
- `#each` can be shortened to just

  ```
  def each(&block)
    @cs.each(&block)
  end
  ```
- `#put` could be written more idiomatically using `include?`:

  ```
  def put(item)
    @cs << item unless @cs.include?(item)
  end
  ```

  Or you can push the new item immediately, and just call `uniq!` afterward. Or you can use a hash (i.e. instance of `Hash` - not to be confused with the method discussed later), and use its built-in duplicate handling, e.g.:

  ```
  def put(item)
    @cs[item.hash] = item # assumes @cs is a hash
  end
  ```

  Since Ruby 1.9, hashes are ordered too, so in effect it'd be little different from using an array internally.
- `#difference`, `#intersection`, and `#union` can be handled via the internal arrays, e.g.:

  ```
  def difference(other)
    self.class.new(@cs - other.to_a)
  end

  def intersection(other)
    self.class.new(@cs & other.to_a)
  end

  def union(other)
    self.class.new(@cs | other.to_a)
  end
  ```
- And as you can see from the above, those methods should probably be aliased (or renamed) as `-`, `&`, and `|` respectively.
- `@cs.delete(n) if index(n)` - there's no need for the `if` guard. It just requires an extra lookup to do, and slows things down. The call to `delete` will work fine on its own.
- `#==` and `#eql?`. Here you may again use the fact that both `self` and `other` have array representations that already support all this:

  ```
  def ==(other)
    self.class == other.class && @cs == other.to_a
  end
  ```
- I'd include a `dup` method for cloning a set. E.g.:

  ```
  def dup
    self.class.new(@cs)
  end
  ```
- I'd include the [`Enumerable` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html) to get a bunch of methods "for free". All that's required on your class is that it has an `#each` method - which is does.

Now, about your `#hash`. Your method is simply flawed, because it doesn't use `reduce` correctly. Your method is currently equivalent to `(:+).hash` (or, if the set's empty: `:+`). You're simply using `reduce` wrong.

`reduce` takes an initial value and a block. The block, in turn, receives *two* arguments: The value carried over from the previous iteration (or the initial value, first time 'round), and the current element in the array. For instance:

```
sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce(0) do |sum_so_far, item|
  puts "Sum so far: #{sum_so_far}"
  puts "Current value: #{item}"
  sum_so_far += item # this is returned and becomes sum_so_far in the next iteration
end
puts "Final sum: #{sum}"
```

which'll print

```
Sum so far: 0
Current value: 1
Sum so far: 1
Current value: 2
Sum so far: 3
Current value: 3
Final sum: 6
```

As you can hopefully tell, your use of `reduce` is very different.

What you seem to be trying to do is either

```
@cs.reduce(0) { |sum, member| sum += member.hash }
```

or

```
@cs.map(&:hash).reduce(0, &:+)
```

which are functionally identical ways of doing the same thing: Sum the hash values of each object in the set.

However, this approach seems flawed to me, since you'd risk conflicts. A set with just one member might have the hash 7 (the member's hash), and a set with two members might also have a hash of 7 (because the members' hashes are 3 and 4). That's no good.

Honestly, I'd consider simply not implementing `#hash` unless you have very good reason to do so. You have `==`/`eql?` to check for equality, so why bother with `hash`? Easier to let the default implementation handle that.

Comment: assert_equal CustomSet.new([1, 3]), CustomSet.new([3, 1]) will not work with the suggested equal method, by using to_a, members have to be tested individually.

Comment: Also since Ruby does type conversion, the comparison has to support that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986896/distinguish-between-index-of-a-decimal-number-and-integer-inside-an-array-in-rub

Comment: @gitarchie Ah, right, good point